# Optimization of an open box

Tags: calculus

> If 900 square cm of material is available to make a box with a square base and open top, what is the largest possible volume?

The answer is $2598$ cm$^3$, but I don't know how one gets this answer. I know to differentiate the volume at $x=0$, and with that being my inflection point(s) I determine concavity using the second derivative. If concavity is down, then that inflection is a maximum. If concavity is up, then that inflection is a minimum. Right?

I don't know how to obtain the volume and use the given constraint, however.

Answer (score 1):

You have an open box with a square base and 4 walls. Let $a$ be the length of one side on the base, and $b$ be the length of one of the sides on the walls.

Your surface area will be $a^2 + 4ab$. You have $900$ square centimeters to make the box, so
\begin{align}
900 &= a^2 + 4ab &\\
\frac{900-a^2}{4a} &= b &\\
\end{align}

The volume of the box will be $V = a^2b$. You want to maximize this, so
\begin{align}
V = a^2b &= a^2 (\frac{900-a^2}{4a}) &\\
V &= \frac{900a-a^3}{4} &\\
\end{align}

Now you want to maximize this, so
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{da} = 0 &\\
\frac{dV}{da}\frac{900a-a^3}{4} &= 0 &\\
a &= \sqrt{300} \approx 17.321 \text{ cm}&\\
\end{align}

Now we know $a$. Use this to find $b$:
\begin{align}
b &= \frac{900-a^2}{4a} &\\
b &\approx 8.660 \text{ cm}&\\
\end{align}

Now calculate the volume: $a^2b = 2598 \text{ cm}^3$.

Comment: I don't follow any of this at all. The volume formula even confuses me, because it looks like it implies height = 1, but I don't see where in the word problem that suggests height is 1.

Comment: Do you understand the part where the box has a base with surface area $a^2$ and sides $4*ab$?

Comment: I understand why there's a multiple of 4 because there are 4 walls of length b. what I don't understand is why we have an additional multiple of a? why 4ab and not 4b if the box is open?

Comment: The walls each have a surface area of $ab$. The base for the walls are length $a$ and height $b$. As you said, there are $4$ walls, so this is multiplied by $4$ to get $4ab$.

Comment: ah i see now, i understand surface area now. but how do i derive the volume area you provided?

Comment: The volume of the box is the bottom of the box multiplied by the height. In this case, the bottom of the box is $a^2$, and the height is $b$. So $V= a^2b$.